# INVALID_ARGUMENT response when signingBlob using IamCredentialsClient

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm following this google guide on [how to sign urls manually](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-manually#algorithm) since I need to create a signed URL in other to let other user upload files without having to authenticate manually and while I manage to follow all steps required and showed in the [python example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/f5d43e6da566e80ee1d216e75bd24c7afaf5f8fc/storage/signed_urls/generate_signed_urls.py), my java code always receives an `io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument`.

I'm getting crazy trying to find what is the issue and I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

The dependency I'm using to `signBlob` is the [google-cloud-iamcredentials](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-iamcredentials/latest/overview). Is there something I'm missing out?

Here you can check the code

```
try (IamCredentialsClient iamCredentialsClient = IamCredentialsClient.create()){
        final LocalDateTime currentTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        final String completeTimeStamp = currentTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd HHmmss"))
                .replace(" ", "T") + 'Z';
        final String pathToResource = "/" + filename;
        final String credentialScope = currentTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE) + "/eu/storage/goog4_request";
        String credential = clientEmail + '/' + credentialScope;
        credential = credential.replace("@", "%40");
        credential = credential.replace("/", "%2F");
        final String canonicalHeader = "host:" + bucketName + ".storage.googleapis.com\n";
        final String signedHeader = "host";
        final String canonicalQueryString =
                "X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&" +
                        "X-Goog-Credential=" + credential + '&' +
                        "X-Goog-Date=" + completeTimeStamp + '&' +
                        "X-Goog-Expires=" + expiration + '&' +
                        "X-Goog-SignedHeaders=" + signedHeader;
        final String canonicalRequest =
                "PUT" + '\n' +
                pathToResource + '\n' +
                canonicalQueryString + '\n' +
                canonicalHeader + '\n' +
                signedHeader + '\n' +
                "UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD";
        final String hashedCanonicalRequest =
                DigestUtils.sha256Hex(canonicalRequest.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        final String stringToSign = "GOOG4-RSA-SHA256" + '\n' +
                completeTimeStamp + '\n' +
                credentialScope + '\n' +
                hashedCanonicalRequest;
        final String signature = iamCredentialsClient.signBlobCallable()
                .call(
                        SignBlobRequest.newBuilder()
                                .setName(ServiceAccountName.of(projectId, clientEmail).toString())
                                .addAllDelegates(new ArrayList<>())
                                .setPayload(ByteString.copyFrom(stringToSign.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))
                                .build()
                ).toString();
        return String.format(CLOUD_URL, pathToResource,
                canonicalQueryString, "&X-Goog-Signature=".concat(signature));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found my issue after a long time debugging and an even longer time having a break from this problem.

Turns out I was creating the `ServiceAccountName.of` wrong, according to this resource https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/signBlob.

You can see under the parameter section this comment

> Required. The resource name of the service account for which the credentials are requested, in the following format: projects/-/serviceAccounts/{ACCOUNT_EMAIL_OR_UNIQUEID}. The - wildcard character is required; replacing it with a project ID is invalid.

Meaning my code was not constructing this field in the correct format, I changed `ServiceAccountName.of(projectId, clientEmail).toString()` to `ServiceAccountName.of("-", clientEmail).toString()` and it worked!

I leave this as the answer for my question in case anyone in the future encounters with this exact issue.